# WSL's 'bash.exe test.sh' won't execute .bashrc whereas just issuing 'bash.exe' does

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

From within my WSL environment (Windows 11, WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04 distribution), let's suppose I add the following line to my `.bashrc` file:

```
[...]
echo ".bashrc executed"
```

If I open a CMD command prompt, create a file `test.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test"
```

then execute:

```
C:\Users\andy> bash.exe test.sh
```

I get the following:

```
Test
```

I would expect:

```
.bashrc executed
Test
```

Now, if I just do this:

```
C:\Users\andy> bash
```

I do get

```
.bashrc executed
```

My question is: how can I run `bash` so that `.bashrc` is (indeed) executed and then execute `test.sh`?

Comment: This is (massively) documented behavior. Noninteractive shells do not and should not source files for interactive use. If you want to source something both from your script and from `.bashrc`, put it in a separate file and do exactly that.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put this in a separate file because my problem is that third-party components placed everything into .bashrc (rvm and other components). Isn't there a way I can force bash to execute .bashrc?

Comment: I need .bash_profile to be executed too, which bash -i does not execute.

Comment: RIght, I see that 'bash -l' can be used to execute bash as a login shell, which does execute .bash_profile (and not .bashrc). My gosh, so many options.

Comment: Whatever `nvm` put there can be moved to a different file; it's not like they will take out your own `source` statements, or insist on putting back stuff you have moved elsewhere (unless they are severely broken, in which case file a bug report).

Comment: Why do you expect a different behaviour? See `man bash`, section  _INVOCATION_, which describes under which conditions .bashrc is sourced.

Comment: Sorry, I actually was totally unaware of this difference of behavior. Thanks for the pointer to INVOCATION, I am now studying this part. I am questioning myself about the usefulness of this fragmentation of functionality.